# Erro publicação projeto C# MVC, Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um projeto C# em MVC, que rodando no Visual Studio 2013, funciona, porém quando subo para o servidor dá este erro:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Erro depois da solução apresentada

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Helpers'
>   does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?)

```
Line 32:     <pages>
Line 33:       <namespaces>
Line 34:         <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
Line 35:         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
Line 36:         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
```

Comment: Qual provedor de hospedagem? Locaweb, kinghost?

Comment: smarterasp.net, tenho outras aplicações hospedadas lá sem nenhum problema. Estava tento problema em abrir o projeto em duas máquinas diferentes, pois pedia MVC 4.0.0.1 em uma e a outra tinha somente 4.0.0.0

Comment: Erro completo http://app.sesmt.com.br/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que a DLL não está sendo copiada para o servidor na hora de publicar.

Dentro do projeto, clique em **References**, selecione essa DLL, clique com o botão direito e em **Properties**. Troque a opção **Copy Local** para **true** e publique a aplicação novamente.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "dentro do projeto"? Que projeto? Onde seria isso? Não tem como fazer na configuração direta no IIS?

Comment: @franzisk No arquivo csproj. Tem ué, só copiar a DLL pra lá, agora se é uma boa ideia eu já não posso garantir...

Comment: É que é um projeto que foram copiados uns arquivos de um sistema que está em produção e colocado numa pasta no servidor e estamos tentando subir configurando direto no IIS (Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3429.0), por isso gostaria de saber como resolver direto ou no Web.config ou no painel do IIS